# Add a dot after chapter and section/figure/table number in ToC/LoF/LoT using tocstyle

Tags: table-of-contents, punctuation, tocstyle

I am using package `tocstyle` package to format my ToC/LoF/LoT lists. I saw already some answers using other packages, but none with `tocstyle`. And the use of `tocstyle` is "mandatory". I want to have a dot after chapter and section/figure/table number in ToC/LoF/LoT, but I was not able to achieve that trying to use `\settocfeature{}{}`. For example (notice the dot after the number and before the text itself).

```
ToC
1. Chapter 1 ............................................................ 4

LoF
1.1. Figure 1 ........................................................... 7

LoT
1.1. Table 1 ............................................................ 8
```

My MWE is below:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocstyle}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

```
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}
```

to your preamble, which will insert a `.` after all numbers in the ToC.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocstyle}
\newcommand{\autodot}{.}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't unable to get this to compile...is `\autodot` defined in `report` or `tocstyle`?

Comment: The `\renewcommand{\autodot}` does not work because `\autodot` was not defined. But `\newcommand{\autodot}{.}` works!

Comment: @Guho: Sorry, fixed.

Comment: @cacamailg: Thanks; I blame it on my debugging skills.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Setting `\autodot` to `.` results in the dot being included in the TOC output/formatting, hence, `\autodot` is already used in the respective command. However, `\autodot` is *not defined* until `\newcommand{autodot}{.}`. How does the unmodified code not throw an `Undefined control sequence` error? I didn't see anything in `tocstyle` that checked if `\autodot` was defined.

Comment: @Guho I didn't look to the code of `tocstyle`. But it should have a test condition to check if `\autodot` was defined. If it was defined, use it! That is why `\renewcommand` does not work because `\autodot` was not defined it.

Comment: How to do this for list of figures?

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine `tocstyle`'s version of `\numberline` to add the dot:

```
\makeatletter
    \let\oldtocstyle@numberline\tocstyle@numberline
    \def\tocstyle@numberline#1{\oldtocstyle@numberline{#1.}}
\makeatother
```